# Displaying a list of checkboxes and text field after radio is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a form that has the following fields:

```
<div>
     <input name="department" type="radio" value="1" required >
     <label for="Orchestra">Orchestra</label>
</div>
<div>
      <input name="department" type="radio" value="2">
     <label for="Band">Band</label>
</div>
```

What I would like to be able to do is to display different checkboxes and comment text fields ONLY if the radio button for "Band" is checked. If this is unchecked then, the checkboxes should go away. I found several examples online, but for some reason I can't get them to work. The problem must be that I do not know Javascript or JQuery :(  Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried different things that I have seen on stackOverflow and other websites, but I am so clueless about Javascript that I can't get it to work.

Comment: So what did you try ?

Comment: *The problem must be that I do not know Javascript or JQuery* - I admire your honesty. You should start by learning it, and you'll figure it out

Comment: Could you show the rendered HTML, not the PHP, given that this is JavaScript.

Comment: I am learning Javascript after I am done mastering PHP; I think that without knowing javascript things are going to be really hard. @David Thomas, I deleted the PHP code and left just html. Thanks for taking the time to review this.

Comment: @komodo -- I wouldn't really ignore other key aspects of web dev while you "master" another - if you're doing full stack dev - you need to know JavaScript

Comment: You should get an approach where you learn the necessary things altogether. After all, you can't separate them if you want to see a fully functional solution. You'll need at least a bit of everything that's involved.

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody! I will be buying a Javascript and JQuery book then. I hope I can find a solution to this problem way before I am done with the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a commented fiddle to help you accomplish what you ask, but also clue you in on what's actually going on. I recommend really diving into JavaScript/JQuery with the many resources available online, but for now, I hope my comments will help get you started.

The main takeaway here, is we use JavaScript to "listen" to whether or not the input in question is selected, not selected—based on that value, we can dictate what our view will look like—in this case, hiding or showing element(s).

#### JS

```
$(function () {

    // Create selectors for relevant DOM elements
    var $Department = $('input[name="department"]');
    var $BandSelected = $('#BandSelected');

    // Create a function that you pass 
    // the value of the input element in question.
    // Return TRUE/FALSE based on equality to 2, 
    // the `value` associated with the 'Band' input 
    function isBandsSelected(val) {
        return val == 2;
    }

    // Attach an event listener on `click' of inputs
    $Department.click(function () {
        // Assign a variable to the function that determines if the input
        // we click on is 'Band' (has a value of 2)
        var showBand = isBandsSelected($(this).val());

        // If `showBand` returns TRUE, show our `BandSelected` div
        if (showBand) {
            $BandSelected.show();
            // If `showBand` returns FALSE, show our `BandSelected` div
        } else {
            $BandSelected.hide();
        }
    });

});
```

#### Markup

```
<div>
    <input name="department" type="radio" value="1" required>
    <label for="Orchestra">Orchestra</label>
</div>

<div>
    <input name="department" type="radio" value="2">
    <label for="Band">Band</label>
</div>

<div id="BandSelected" class="hidden">
    Band is selected
</div>
```

#### Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4x1ybqyv/

Comment: Thank you SO much for such a detailed explanation. JavaScript looks hard to understand. Well, in spite of your wonderful explanation I couldn't get it to work. I wonder if it is due to a conflict with other type of code I have on my website or something. I think I need to study the code you gave me and I will come back in a few days after I figure this out. Thanks a lot!